# Почему не корректно работает отправка почты

Tags: php, html, email

Здравствуйте! Не могу понять, почему не совсем корректно работает отправка почты с автоматическим ответом. (Первичная отправка работает без проблем, авто-ответ не срабатывает)

$send - пробовал и с точкой и без точки, и другую переменную и прочую ерунду, но все равно :(

А, и ещё в переменной $sendfrom, почему то удаляются всегда пробелы с текста. Почему? В остальных местах пробелы везде срабатывают норм, тут нет :( причем \r\n не помогает...

```
<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { if (!empty($_POST['uname']) && (!empty($_POST['uemail']) && (!empty($_POST['umessage'])))){
if (isset($_POST['uname'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['uname'])){
      $uname = strip_tags($_POST['uname']) . "<br>";
      $unameInput = "<b>Имя:</b><br>";
     }
}
if (isset($_POST['uemail'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['uemail'])){
      $uemail = strip_tags($_POST['uemail']) . "<br>";
      $uemailInput = "<b>Почта:</b><br>";
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['umessage'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['umessage'])){
      $umessage = strip_tags($_POST['umessage']) . "<br>";
      $umessageInput = "<b>Сообщение:</b><br>";
    }
}
        if (isset($_POST['uphone'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['uphone'])){
      $uphone = strip_tags($_POST['uphone']) . "<br>";
      $uphoneInput = "<b>Телефон:</b><br>";
    }
}
$to  = "mail@skgs.su" . ", "; /*адрес, на который должно приходить письмо*/
$to .= "angel-nwn@yandex.ru" . ", ";
$sendfrom = "Comfort System"; /*адрес, с которого будет приходить письмо */
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit \r\n";
$subject = "Сообщение с сайта";
$subject2 = "Автоответ на письмо";
$body2 = 'Здравствуйте, $name\r\n.<br> Пожалуйста, не отвечайте на это письмо. Оно сформировано автоматически.<br> Вы написали нам письмо, со следующим текстом:';
$message = "$unameInput $uname
            $uemailInput $uemail
            $uphoneInput $uphone
            $umessageInput $umessage";

$send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$send .= mail ($uemail, $subject2, $message, $headers);
  if ($send == 'true'){ 
         echo '<p class="success">Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!</p>'; 
    } 
  else { echo '<p class="fail"><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!</b></p>';
    }
 } 
  else {
     echo '<p class="fail">Ошибка. Вы заполнили не все обязательные поля!</p>';
     }
 } 
  else {
    header ("Location: http://skgs.su"); // главная страница
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте

На мой взгляд проблема заключается в строке:

```
$send .= mail ($uemail, $subject2, $message, $headers);
```

Во-первых, Вы пытается присоединить к bool-результату первой функции `mail()` результат второй, поэтому проверка далее не будет работать корректно.

Во-вторых, переменная `$uemail` при присвоении:

```
$uemail = strip_tags($_POST['uemail']) . "<br>";
```

получает `<br>`, т.е. если `$_POST['uemail']` содержит `test@site.com`, то в результате присвоения будет `$uemail = 'test@site.com<br>'`, поэтому функция `mail()` ничего отправлять на этот email не будет.

P.S. 
На счет `$sendfrom`, скорее всего проблемы из-за того, что заголовок From не совсем правильно формируется.

Попробуйте внести такие изменения:

```
$sendfrom = "Comfort System"; 
$mailfrom = "no-reply@domain.com"; // domain.com замените на ваш домен
$header = "From: ".$sendfrom." <".$mailfrom."> \r\n";
```

Comment: Я Вас понял, однако вопрос стоит в том, что подобный код я нашел в своё время на просторах рунета, естественно его видоизменил довольно сильно. И всё работало. Когда захотел добавить автоответ, используя ТОТ же код (а точнее именно вторую строчку send), работать перестало. Хотя у первоисточника работало всё хорошо.

Comment: И как тогда проще будет добавить перенос на новую строчку в такой код ?:)

Comment: Так, ну в коде то я разобрался. Не могу разобраться почему переменная $sendfrom криво работает.